# Using user input to plot data in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to build a program, in which a user would enter the desired part of data to plot and the R program would plot it. For example:

```
n<- function(){
readline(prompt="enter x value to plot")
}
m<- function{
readline(prompt="enter y value to plot")
}
attach(dataset)
plot(unquote(n()), unquote(m()), main="Scatterplot Example", pch=20)
```

yet this doesnt work, the plot function doesnt recognise the m() and n()?
Am I missing somehing?

Thank you.

Comment: How is `unquote` defined? There is a syntax error in your definition of `m`. Always report error messages if something "doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `attach`.

```
n<- function(){
  readline(prompt="enter x value to plot: ")
}
m<- function(){
  readline(prompt="enter y value to plot: ")
}

plotfun <- function(dat) {
  colx <- n()
  coly <- m()
  plot(dat[,colx], dat[,coly], main="Scatterplot Example", pch=20)      
}

if(interactive()) plotfun(dat=iris)
#enter x value to plot: Sepal.Length
#enter y value to plot: Sepal.Width
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm still a noob when it comes to R so this really helps.